# Some sort of issue with simple int/double operations

Tags: c

I am new to C and I tried to put together a (only slightly) nontrivial piece of code, in which I use an array to store the values of atan(x) in bins of width dx from 0 to 1, then use the rectangular method to compute the integral of atan(x)dx from 0 to 1. The code should loop while successively making dx smaller to see the integral converge to the analytical result. I have been totally unable to figure out why I get expected outputs for most entries in the loop, but (some number)e+268 for the 7th/8th/15th outputs; I imagine it has something to do with int/double casting but the irregularity of it is very strange to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int array_len = 20;
    int array_len_new;
    int num_conv = 18;
    double linspace[200];
    double conv_array[200];
    double PI = 3.142857;
    double result;
    int i;
    int j;
            
    for (i = 0; i < num_conv; i++) {
        array_len_new = array_len + 10*i;
        double dx = 1./array_len_new;
        for (j = 0; j < array_len_new; j++) {
            linspace[j] = j* 1.0/array_len_new;
            conv_array[i] += atan(linspace[j])*dx;
        }
        printf("Result for %d bins is: %e\n", array_len_new, conv_array[i]);
    }

    printf("Converged result: %e\n", (PI-log(4.))/4.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Result for 20 bins is: 4.190854e-001
Result for 30 bins is: 4.256883e-001
Result for 40 bins is: 4.289811e-001
Result for 50 bins is: 4.309539e-001
Result for 60 bins is: 4.322680e-001
Result for 70 bins is: 4.332061e-001
Result for 80 bins is: 2.308177e+268
Result for 90 bins is: 2.308177e+268
Result for 100 bins is: 4.348934e-001
Result for 110 bins is: 4.352511e-001
Result for 120 bins is: 4.355492e-001
Result for 130 bins is: 4.358013e-001
Result for 140 bins is: 4.360175e-001
Result for 150 bins is: 4.362047e-001
Result for 160 bins is: 2.316093e+268
Result for 170 bins is: 4.365131e-001
Result for 180 bins is: 4.366416e-001
Result for 190 bins is: 4.367566e-001
Converged result: 4.391407e-001
```

EDIT: I have found that the issue resolves itself if I change the length of conv_array (which only needs 18 values, I made it big because I thought it wouldn't matter) from 200 to 18, or even 100. Why could this possibly be the case?

Comment: You must use `%lf` as format specifier for a `double`.

Comment: @nomoresigsegv: `%e` is an appropriate conversion specification for printing a `double`.

Comment: This does not reproduce for me; all outputs are around .4. What compiler are you using, including version, what switches did you compile with, what system, including version, are you running on?

Comment: What do you see when you print the value of each computed value: `array_len_new`, `dx`, `linspace[j]`, and `atan(linspace[j])`?

Comment: What's the point of using arrays for `linspace` and `conv_array`?  It looks like you could use (and re-use) scalar `double` variables for both of those.

Comment: I used MinGW 6.3, which I installed from SourceForge to use with VSCode because it seemed easy. But it seems to be an issue with me not initializing the arrays. And the reason I did multiple arrays is because this was a contrived test case of operations on multiple multi-dim. arrays, so no I did not implement the "nobody on stackexchange will whine at you" way because I, like everyone else who posts here, have my own world and my own goals which extend much further than a text box on a website. Thanks to those who tried to reproduce this error.

Comment: `double PI = 3.142857;`???  https://www.google.com/search?q=value+of+pi or `3.141592653589793238`

Comment: Nobody here is whining at you.  If we point out perceived shortcomings in your code that do not seem relevant to the question you posed, then you should understand that (1) yes, we are trying to help you even more than you asked, but that (2) the world does not revolve around you. Most of the regulars here are interested in the questions and answers here at SO being genuinely useful to posterity, perhaps even more so than in them being specifically useful to you.  That may include making remarks about all manner of code issues.

Answer (score 1):

You do not initialize the elements of `conv_array`.  As a non-`static` local variable, its initial value is indeterminate.  In particular, it is not safe to assume that it will be zero-initialized, but your code relies on exactly that assumption.  Declaring it with an initializer should help:

```
    // ...
    double linspace[200];
    double conv_array[200] = {0};
    double PI = 3.14159265358979;
    // ...
```

The `= {0}` says that the first element is to be initialized to 0, and if any element is initialized then those without explicit initializers are implicitly default-initialized (to 0).

Personally, however, I would not use an array at all where you use `conv_array`, nor where you use `linspace`.  Try this on for size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int base_num_bins = 20;
    int num_cycles = 18;
    double PI = 3.14159265358979;
            
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cycles; i++) {
        int num_bins = base_num_bins + 10 * i;
        double dx = 1. / num_bins;
        double integral = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < num_bins; j++) {
            integral += atan((double) j / num_bins) * dx;
        }
        printf("Result for %d bins is: %e\n", num_bins, integral);
    }

    printf("Converged result: %e\n", (PI - log(4.)) / 4.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`conv_array` has not been initialised, but you do

```
conv_array[i] += atan(linspace[j])*dx;
```

I suggest

```
double conv_array[200] = { 0 };
```

Side issue:

```
double PI = 3.142857;
```

might be ok with `float` but it isn't a very accurate value for ***π*** when working with `double`. I suggest using `M_PI` instead of `double PI;` and with MSVC you'll also need

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```